# Admin values of an attribute from filter.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I am trying to get the admin values of an attribute from `app/design/frontend/{package_name}/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml`. From this file I am able to get the attribute code (i.e., the admin label of the attribute) and `$_item->getValue()` only gives me the escaped current store value. I am able to get the admin value of an attribute for a specific product from `app/design/frontend/{package_name}/default/template/catalog/view.phtml` though:

```
$productAdminAttributeValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the values of an attribute:

```
<?php

  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code'); 
  $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
  foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
      $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
      $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
  }
?>
```